# How can append child elements of an element within the same element with some changes

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have the following html code

```
<button id="button_id" class="scalable add" title="Add email" type="button" onclick="emailsControl.addItem()" style="">
<tbody id="email_chain_container">
    <tr>
        <td class="nobr">
            <input type="file" id="chain_Image_1"  name="Image[1]" class="input-text" />
        </td>
        <td class="last"><input type="hidden"  class="delete" name="email_chain[delete][]" />
            <button onclick="emailsControl.deleteItem(event);return false" class="scalable delete icon-btn delete-product-option" title="Delete Image"><span><?php echo $this->__('Delete')?></span>   
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

when click on the button, i want to get the elements inside tbody and change the index in input element to index+1 and then append the element again to the tbody. This is the rough code i have used for it. However its not working

```
emailsControl = {
    addItem: function ()
    {
        var chainParent = document.getElementById('email_chain_container');
        var index = chainParent.childNodes.length; //get the number of tr elements present in tbody
        var repeat = chainParent.innerHTML;
        var newHTML = repeat.replace(index, (index + 1)).
        replace('Image[' + (index) + ']', 'Image[' + (index + 1) + ']');
        document.chainParent.appendChild(newHTML);
    },
}
```

How can I do it in most effective way?Please suggest your ideas. Thanks in advance

Comment: Your `tbody` isn't within a `table`?

Comment: I see you are using jquery. Why not make better use of the library by using its traversing functions. There's even a filter() and attr() method you can call. http://api.jquery.com/category/Traversing/

Comment: var chainParent=$('#email_chain_container'); and change here.

Comment: @JamesMontagne : yes it is inside a table

Comment: jquery is also acceptable. However function call should be in the obj.function() format]

Comment: It looks like you are using jQuery. '$' sign is used to define/access jQuery

Comment: both jquery and js is acceptable. sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: but i am prefering js more to solve this. there is no reason for that:))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have done it. Dont know whether this is the best method. But it worked !!!

```
<script type="text/javascipt">
emailsControl = 
{
     addItem : function () 
     {
         var chainParent = document.getElementById( 'email_chain_container' );
         var trElements = chainParent . getElementsByTagName("tr");
         var index = trElements . length;
         var childElements = trElements[0] . innerHTML;
         var newHTML = childElements . replace( /1/g , (index+1))
         var tr = document . createElement('tr');
         tr . innerHTML = newHTML;
         chainParent . appendChild (tr);        

   },
}
</script>
```